How to prevent screen recording in macOS app
Is there any way to disable the screen recording in AppDelegate in a macOS application?
I used UIScreen.main.isCaptured and NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(preventScreenRecording), name: UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification, object: nil) in an iOS application and it does work correctly but in m  project isCaptured method has been deprecated.
I am looking for equivalent code for UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification and UIScreen.main.isCaptured in a macOS project.
It does work well on iOS application
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

  override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptionslaunchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(preventScreenRecording), name: UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    if let window = window {
      makeSecure(window: window)
    }

      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    
  @objc func preventScreenRecording() {
    let isCaptured = UIScreen.main.isCaptured
    print("isCaptured: \(isCaptured)")
    if isCaptured {
        blurScreen()
    }
    else {
        removeBlurScreen()
    }
}


This isn't supported on macOS as far as I know.
